# R function that can sum of every x values, overlapping the data for each calculation?

Tags: r

I am new to R and have never posted on this website before, so if I haven't provided enough information or if this is badly phrased, I apologize in advance.

I have a data frame that represents energy data every 5 minutes. To find the basal rate over the entire day, I want to sum every 5 values (for a 30-minute period) and find the lowest value every 5 minutes

So if I had (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) with each letter representing a data point, I would want it to find the sum of:

1. (a, b, c, d, e, f)
2. (b, c, d, e, f, g)
3. (c, d, e, f, g, h)
4. (d, e, f, g, h, i)

If the function can choose which of these 4 is the lowest, that would be perfect, but if it can just provide me sums in a new column, I could just sort that with another function.

My data looks like this (but a lot longer, not sure if I should post the whole thing):

```
Time Value
1:00 5.5
1:05 5.3
1:10 5.4
1:15 6.3
1:20 4.6
1:25 6.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rollsum` function from `zoo` to calculate rolling sum. Based on where you want to put the answer you can `align` the output accordingly.

For example, right align - when you want to sum of position 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 should be put at position 5.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% mutate(roll_sum = rollsumr(Value, 5, fill = NA))

#  Time Value roll_sum
#1 1:00   5.5       NA
#2 1:05   5.3       NA
#3 1:10   5.4       NA
#4 1:15   6.3       NA
#5 1:20   4.6     27.1
#6 1:25   6.4     28.0
```

Left align - when you want to put sum of position 1 to 5 at position 1.

```
df %>% mutate(roll_sum = rollsum(Value, 5, fill = NA, align = 'left'))

#  Time Value roll_sum
#1 1:00   5.5     27.1
#2 1:05   5.3     28.0
#3 1:10   5.4       NA
#4 1:15   6.3       NA
#5 1:20   4.6       NA
#6 1:25   6.4       NA
```

Center align - When you want to sum of position 1 to 5 to be included at position 3.

```
df %>% mutate(roll_sum = rollsum(Value, 5, fill = NA))

#  Time Value roll_sum
#1 1:00   5.5       NA
#2 1:05   5.3       NA
#3 1:10   5.4     27.1
#4 1:15   6.3     28.0
#5 1:20   4.6       NA
#6 1:25   6.4       NA
```

Note that in all the case the numbers are the same but the position at which answers are placed differs. If you store the output of above operation in `result`, you can get minimum value by doing `min(result$roll_sum, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the rollmean function in the zoo library, eg:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Avg_5period=zoo::rollmean(Value,k=5,fill=NA))
```